# get: present or past

Tags: tense, verbs

1. OK, I get the message – I’m going!
2. OK, I got the message – I’m going!
3. OK, I've got the message – I’m going!

The sentence 1 is a sentence from Longman Dictionary, but it seems to me grammatically inappropriate. I think it should be in form of the sentence 2 or 3. Because they don't get the message in *simple present* or even *present continuous*, are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I get the message" is idiomatic, and is indeed what people actually say.

While the other two may be more grammatically correct, and in fact 3 is marginally more correct than 2, it's not so much what people tend to say.